# Save a Favicon in ubuntu for PHP page

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, favicon

i want to add a favicon to my PHP page at my Ubuntu server. unfortunately, i don't know how to add an image (favicon.ico) to my server an save it there. I tried to find an answer to that but it seems like i'm eather searching wrong or i just don't understand it properly...
Ubuntu 18.04.5

thanks for any help!

Comment: You put the file in the directory the website is served from. The OS isn't really relevant. Nor is the language used to generate the HTML for it.

Comment: Note that you should always clear your browser cache after updating your site before testing your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. At the very least you will want a favicon.ico file on every website or web application to identify your company or application's brand.

A "favicon.ico" file is nothing but an image file with your brands icon. But it needs to be in a particular format (ico) for web browsers to read it.

Web browsers use this .ico file whenever you bookmark a webpage to give a visual identification to the resource you are saving.

All that aside, you can convert a graphic to .ico format yourself using image editing software or use many online tools to convert regular images or graphics to this format. If you use an online service (recommended), then you will generally need to follow the guidelines of these services in order to convert your image to the proper format.

Here's an example online service that will create the .ico image you desire. After using the service you will want to place the .ico file in the 'root' directory of your website and/or application. The 'root' directory means the very base directory in which your website files exist. E.g. your index.html or index.php file, etc.

> https://www.favicon-generator.org/

In addition, you can explicitly reference your favicon via HTML meta tags. See this W3C URL for additional reference:

> https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon